# Error : Connect ENETUNREACH

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook-graph-api, remote-server

I am fetching videos from the facebook graph api(24*7) using nodejs. My code is working fine but after every 3 or 4 days it stops working and gives the following error: (Ignore the I'm in loop statements)

[image: Error file]

> Error: connect ENETUNREACH 2a03:2990:f015:12:face:b00c:0:2:443 - Local (:::0)
>   at Object._errnoException (util.js:1003:13)
>   at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js.1024:20)
>   ...

Comment: I get a similar error when I try to run a node.js program from rc.local. Runs fine when I run it manually. Curious to see a suggestion on how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Solved my problem by making sure network services were up before rc.local was run. This was done by running `raspi-config` on my RaspberryPi (where I am running the scripts) and setting `boot options … wait for network at boot … yes`

Answer (score 5):

Check you internet connection . That solved my problem as ENETUNREACH is a network issue such as host unreachable or your gateway not working .

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I just changed the `localhost` property to `127.0.0.1` as follows:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  // host     : 'localhost', // localhost causes somehow this error
  host: '127.0.0.1',
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar error, I disabled IPv6 on my computer and then the error stopped occurring.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It also worked on my side

Answer (score -3):

I got the same issue. My problem was I still have the corp proxy settings in `npm` config. My resolution:

1. Check if any proxy settings in place

```
npm config list
```

2. Remove them

```
npm config delete https-proxy
```

You may have more. But after that, the error's gone.